# How to clip multiple textures to polygon in three js

Tags: three.js, webgl, rendering, clipping

I have a bunch of planes each with their own texture in a grid. Currently I am rendering these as separate planes, each with their own texture, although I could use a single plane with multiple faces.

[image: textures]

Each color is a texture.

I have a polygon mesh with arbitrary shape that is parallel to these planes:

[image: polygon]

This shape could be completely contained within one of the planes, or larger.

I would like to texture the polygon with the overlapping textures of the planes:

[image: overlap]

How do I accomplish this clipping of the textures in three js?

I am also open to any other WebGL solutions.

A few ideas I had:

1. Subdivide the polygon into faces that correspond with the overlapping planes. Then texture these faces using UV coords. I know I can get this to work, but it seems like too complicated of a solution.
2. Apply multiple textures to the polygon and use UV coordinates to distribute them. -- Im not sure this is possible without subdividing?

Any other ideas? Can this be accomplished with blending modes?

Comment: Just an idea, most probably not very efficient. Can't you draw all your textures on 2d canvas in needed order and then simple map one texture on the polygon?

Comment: great idea. I think I will try rendering to a texture. It should be efficient enough for my basic use case. It still seems over complicated though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few ideas:

---

Bake small textures into [texture atlas](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/2530/practical_texture_atlases.php) so you have tiles on single plane with one uv set (if more that one atlases needed you could use multiple texture samplers in one WebGL program).

**Compute plane's uv corresponding to world pos of shape vertex and sample texture atlas with these uv.** For this you probably need to pass to shape material plane's modelMatrix (or just scale/offset if you know its orientation, or nothing if plane is fixed).

Keep in mind that you don't need high resolution textures on small tiles. Also **atlas could be replaced by rendering tiles to texture** (from top with orthographic projection)
**or by passing textures in separate samplers**. About last case: to determine which textures are to be passed you could test bounding box of shape versus map tiles.

---

**Render your shape with simple material to a texture and use this texture as mask in main pass where you draw planes.**

Detailed on that:

Place shapes you want to mask in separate container and [render it to a fixed size texture](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-render-to-a-texture-in-threejs--cms-25686) with very simple material (write white everywhere) with your regular camera. After that render pass you should have a texture with black color and white shape on it as you would see it on screen (but scaled to square texture).

After that render the rest of scene passing to tiles materials mask texture. In fragment shader sample mask texture with screenPos as uv and draw fragment only if you get white (else discard). Probably not the best idea (discard is expensive).

---

**Better version of depth mask approach**: in mask pass disable color writing (`renderer.context.colorMask(false, false, false, false);`). After that you should have your shape in depth buffer. Then reset color mask back to all `true`, set `renderer.autoClearDepth = false`, set `tileMaterial.depthFunc = THREE.GreaterDepth` ([more about depthFunc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/depthFunc)). and render your tiles then. This should do the job.

It also could be done with writing mask depth to [depthTexture](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_depth_texture.html) and just using it as a texture in main pass.

---

**Use stencil buffer for masking**: I didn't try it yet, but it should be appropriate for your case. Examples: [1](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/postprocessing/MaskPass.js), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35023275/three-js-usage-with-stencil-buffer). Idea is similar to masking which is described above.

Comment: could you elaborate on the second two? I can't use a texture atlas unless created at runtime because I am loading my texture tiles dynamically at runtime from google maps api.

Comment: @rawbeans added details. Consider passing textures in separate samplers and using world space coords for sampling, I think it shoud work good since there are no additional passes. Amount of available samplers could disturb though.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up rendering to a texture and then computing UVs like in your first suggestion. It works very well.

Comment: @rawbeans glad to hear it!